# Linq nested loop search one specific top level element , collection within collections

Tags: c#, linq, loops

I want to get the company whose employees id card issued with the specific number, sort of finding the exact element inside nested collection.

Using first or default 3 times does not seems to be a correct way.

```
> var company = cprIdentificationReply.Companies
>                    .FirstOrDefault(x => (x.Employee
>                    .FirstOrDefault(y => (y.IDCardIssued
>                    .FirstOrDefault(z => z.CardNumber
>                  .Equals(number,StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))) != null)
> != null));
```

What can be a proper way of achieving the same?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use the `Any` extension method:

```
var companies = cprIdentificationReply.Companies
                                    .Where(x => (x.Employee
                                                  .Any(y => (y.IDCardIssued
                                                              .Any(z => z.CardNumber
              .Equals(number, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                                                                  )
                                                      )
                                           ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want better looking code why don't use LINQ query syntax.
I always find it easier to read LINQ query when looking at someone else's code, especially for complex operations.

Something like this:

```
var company = (from company in cprIdentificationReply.Companies
              from empl in company.Employee
              from idCardIss in empl .IDCardIssued
              where idCardIss.CardNumber.Equals(number, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
              select c).FirstOrDefault();
```